# How to take percentage of total, excluding one field in Tableue?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have revenue for say 5 years:

```
y1 1000
y2 2000
y3  3000
y4  4000
y5  5000
total 15000
```

I want to take y1/total, y2/total etc...

I have the formula

```
SUM([Sales]) / TOTAL(SUM([Sales]))
```

But the issue is that the total includes total, which is a separate row (field) in the data. How to exclude that field?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve percentage of total as well as keep the total segment below like this :

[image: Percentage of Total]

Try this steps

[image]